# Is there a way to create event funnels in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I try to find a way to create (goal) funnels based on multiple events or a mixture of URL pageviews, events and transactions. The only funnel option I can find is with multiple URLS though.

An exemplary use case would be a user who saw a paywall and bought a day pass afterwards. Instead of implementing this as a single event (with an unnecessary complex underlying code structure), it seems more natural to me to track this as two distinct events and define a funnel within Google Analytics.

Is there a way to do this or an even more convenient approach?

Answer (score 1):

According to relevant [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313), only destination type goals are supported for funnels. (Last item in table.) However, this also means, that you can use virtual pageviews instead of events, to track various steps in your funnel.

For example, if paywall isn't implemented as a single page, but a layer is used, you can still push a virtual pageview into Analytics, when the paywall is displayed. This page can be tracked in your goal funnel as one of the funnel steps.

You should also consider, if this isn't going to negatively affect your general page reports. E.g. by significantly increasing your pageviews.

Comment: I will test this, but flexibility seems very limited. The funnel requires the URLs to be called one after another right away. What if I want to measure said funnel (paywall > purchase) session- or user-based? Given the use case, this seems more plausible to me. Not all user will buy a pass right away. Also, the virtual pageviews require additional tracking code increasing GTM's load time.

Comment: Since I have a Single Page Application, I have created virtual page views to track and create funnel visualization. My question is if the user skips one or more virtual page views and goes to final step how will this effect the funnel visualization?

Comment: Virtual and actual pageviews won't have any difference in terms of funnel tracking. Details of funnel tracking: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313